# How we can read document information on spring mvc & mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to get one person record on mongodb with spring mvc using ajax call.

this is ajax code in index.jsp:

```
    $(document).on("click","a.edit",function(){
        var id=this.id;

        $.ajax({
            url:"edit.htm",
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(response){
                alert(response); 
            }
        });
    });
```

This is PersonService Class  get method:

```
public Person getPerson(String id) {
    return mongoOperations.findOne( Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)),
                                Person.class,
                                COLLECTION_NAME) ;
}
```

This is ajaxEditPerson method in PersonController Class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String ajaxEditPerson(
       @ModelAttribute Person person, 
       ModelMap model,
       @RequestParam(value="id") String id) {

      model.addAttribute("personOne", personService.getPerson(id));

     return "test";
}
```

I want to get person infos in index.jsp using ETL:

```
${personOne.name}
```

But it doesnt send response to index.jsp.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you get instead? How is your returned "test" linked to your index.jsp view?

Comment: A person document from person collection

Comment: I am new at spring mvc.I want to person object to link to the index.jsp.Have you any idea how can we do?

Comment: The `@ResponseBody` annotation is similar to `@RequestBody`. This annotation can be put on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name) [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)

Comment: This is not helped me

Answer (score 0):

as  Joram says you are returning String "test" to your controler

But you should return personOne object.

Change your method to following and make sure that your project has Jackson on path or configure json mapping manualy

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Person ajaxEditPerson(
       @ModelAttribute Person person, 
       ModelMap model,
       @RequestParam(value="id") String id) {



     return personService.getPerson(id);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code .It has an error "APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: add import org.springframework.http or use "application/json" string directly

Comment: add import `import org.springframework.http.MediaType;`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different technologies that you can use.

1. When using jsp's the rendering happens on the server. To be able to use index.jsp you need a mapping from your view-name (used in the controller) to the jsp-file.

You can put this in your `servlet-xml`

```
<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/jsp directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Then you put your `index.jsp` in the folder `/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`
In your controller you then have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ajaxEditPerson(
    @ModelAttribute Person person, 
    ModelMap model,
    @RequestParam(value="id") String id) {

    model.addAttribute("personOne", personService.getPerson(id));

    return "index";
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ajaxEditPerson(
    @ModelAttribute Person person, 
    ModelMap model,
    @RequestParam(value="id") String id) {

    model.addAttribute("personOne", personService.getPerson(id));

    return new ModelAndView("index", model);
}
```

in your index.jsp you can then use JSTL to access the objects you have put in your model.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Person Object</title>
</head>
<body>
This is a person Object.<br>
Name: <c:out value="${personOne.name}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

2. As Josef already indicated, the other way (REST like) is to return a json string of the object personOne. This json string is then interpreted on the client side, in the browser, and the rendering happens with javascript code running on the clients browser.
   You need a json serializer on your server to turn the Person object into a json string. A suggestion is to use jackson.

   @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public @ResponseBody Person ajaxEditPerson(@RequestParam String id) {
       return personService.getPerson(id);
   }

In your javascript AJAX call you can then access the json string:

```
$(document).on("click","a.edit",function(){
    var id=this.id;

    $.ajax({
        url:"edit",
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(response){
            // response is an Object: json string of Person
            alert(response.name); 
        }
    });
});
```